# CIFS volume not mounting automatically

Tags: ubuntu, cifs, fstab, automount

My CIFS volume is not mounting automatically while boot (like other partitions). This is relevant part of my /etc/fstab:

```
//leonidas/files    /media/photos   cifs    credentials=/etc/samba/user,rw,uid=root,gid=samba,user,auto,noexec,suid,iocharset=utf8  0   0
```

When I do

```
sudo mount -a
```

It is mounted properly, but I want it to be mounted while boot. Why it is not?

My system is ubuntu 9.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe networking is up at the time at the time the filesystems are mounted.  NFS mounts are started by a script in **/etc/network/if-up.d/mountnfs**.  The comments in mountnfs script say it should also mount CIFS shares.

You might want to try rebooting the system and then manually running the **/etc/network/if-up.d/mountnfs** script to see if any errors are displayed.  If their are errors, add them to your question.

Comment: I'm getting such message: "* if-up.d/mountnfs[]: waiting for interface eth0 before doing NFS mounts"

It is strange, because my only running eth interface is eth1.

Comment: You are going to want to alter the script to reflect the interface as eth1 and not eth0 if you want it to work.